# javascript onclick variable / social widget slider

Tags: javascript, html

I've built a social slider widget using some old code I found somewhere on the internet. I'm not that good at Javascript, but I was wondering if you could give me some advice on how to get it functioning properly.

Right now - it is merely moving the container #example up or down, using the css value margin-top, by 272px. I've set a cap of twice that amount so that the container can't go up more than twice, but I don't know how to get each button to move it properly.

[You can view the slider i've built by clicking here](http://geoffwatsondesign.com/test-slider.html), but I'll post most of the important html i wrote below.

---

```
<script language="javascript">
function example_animate(px) {
  var newMargin = parseInt($('#example').css('margin-top')) + px;
  if(newMargin >= -544 && newMargin < 272) {
    $('#example').animate({
        'marginTop' : newMargin + 'px'
    });
  }
}
</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="socials-menu">
        <a href="#a" class="social-facebook" onclick="example_animate(272)"></a>
        <a href="#b" class="social-twitter" onclick="example_animate(-272)"></a>
        <a href="#c" class="social-youtube" onclick="example_animate(-272)"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="example" class="socials">
        FACEBOOK / TWITTER WIDGET IFRAMES WOULD GO HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How doesn't it function?

Comment: We need to know what the issue is.

Comment: do not use `onclick="..."`

Comment: Did you visit the slider link @Blender ? Try clicking the middle box twice. It keeps scrolling beyond, because I don't know how to set a point for it to stop at. The buttons merely move it + or - 272 margin-top, but I need them to move the container to a specific position.

Comment: @eicto why not? explain please, that functionality doesn't seem broken. it's getting the container #example to stop at the appropriate points. I've uploaded images into the slider so it makes more sense.

Comment: @Farseen because jquery wrap javascrit event model, also it force you to define functions in global scope which is also bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the links to:

```
<a href="#a" class="social-facebook" onclick="example_animate(0)"></a>
<a href="#b" class="social-twitter" onclick="example_animate(-272)"></a>
<a href="#c" class="social-youtube" onclick="example_animate(-544)"></a>
```

And your function to:

```
function example_animate(margin) {
    $('#example').animate({
        'marginTop' : margin + 'px'
    });
}
```

You don't need to over complicate things.